# Question regarding proof that the composite mapping of two one-one maps is one-one

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have come across a question regarding composite mappings.

The question is as follows-

> Prove that the composite mapping of two one-one maps is one-one.

My proof is as follows-

> let us consider two one to one mappings $f : X \to Y$ and $g : Y \to Z$.
>
> Since $g $ is one to one, then if
>
> ${\rm z}_0 = {\rm z}_1$
>
> $\implies$ $g({\rm y}_0) = g({\rm y}_1)$
>
> $\implies$ $g(f({\rm x}_0)) = g(f({\rm x}_1))$
>
> $\implies$ $(g \circ f){\rm x}_0 = (g \circ f){\rm x}_1$
>
> $\implies$ ${\rm x}_0 = {\rm x}_1$
>
> Hence, $(g \circ f)$ is one to one function.

Is my proof considerable ?

Can I be provided with a more formal and a detailed proof ? ( I would like to be as pedantic as possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that $f\circ g$ is one-one you have to start with the equation $f(g(x_0))=f(g(x_1))$ and you have to deduce that $x_0=x_1$, The first step is to us the fact that $f$ is one-one so we get $g(x_0)=g(x_1)$. The next step is to us the fact that $g$ is one-one so we get $x_0=x_1$.

Comment: Is my proof considerable?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The starting point of the proof has to be exactly as I have stated.

Comment: Actually , I meant, is my proof considerable for proving that  $(g \circ f)$ is one to one ?